# Call to restart script from CGI not fully restarting

Tags: c, bash, shell, cgi, uclinux

I'm trying to restart the Boa web server from inside a CGI script written in C.  This is on a ucLinux system.  The call to system("/etc/init.d/boa.sh restart") runs successfully and I see from the logs that Boa is stopped, but it is never started.  Running boa.sh restart from the CLI does work OK.  The boa.sh script is shown below.  Any ideas as to why it's not fully restarting?  Note that the CGI script itself is running within Boa.

```
NAME=boa
PROG=/bin/boa
OPTIONS="-c /etc/"
LOCKFILE=/var/lock/boa
STDLOGFILE=/var/log/boaerrlog.log

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo -n $"Starting $NAME: "
        boa $OPTIONS > /dev/null 2>&1 &
#       boa $OPTIONS >$STDOUTFILE 2>&1 &
        touch $LOCKFILE
        echo "OK"
        ;;
    stop)
        echo -n $"Stopping $NAME: "
        kill -TERM `pidof $NAME` > /dev/null 2>&1
        rm -f $LOCKFILE $PIDFILE > /dev/null 2>&1
        echo "OK"
        ;;
    restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;
    status)
        echo "running"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Does the user running the CGI script have permission to all the files/directories need to start the script up?  You may need to utilize a sudo command through the CGI script to have it gain all needed permissions.

Comment: Yes permissions should be fine, it's a very small embedded system with root as the only user.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Do you have any logging that suggests the stop is actually completing successfully?  Or logging that suggests the start is actually starting?

Comment: Yes /var/log/messages shows Boa shutting down but not starting up.  And I've verified that it's not running after executing "boa.sh restart" from the CGI program.  There's something about it being run from a CGI that's stopping it from working, as it can run fine from the CLI.

Comment: You have all output in the script either going to stdout or /dev/null, can you change the /dev/null to go to a file so you can see if an error is occurring during the running of the start function/module.  The only obvious cause I can think of without the output is that an environment variable that exists in your shell but not in the CGI's shell is needed.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I re-ran the test redirecting the output to a file.  The file contains "
Stopping boa: OK
Starting boa: OK
" but the Boa process is not running once the CGI has finished.

Comment: Did you change `boa $OPTIONS > /dev/null 2>&1 &` to be `boa $OPTIONS >> $STDOUTFILE 2>&1 &`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16475/discussion-between-fred-basset-and-lipongo)

Comment: If the script is being run from within Boa, is it not being killed when Boa is killed? Try detaching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information gathered in a chat.

The process that is being restarted through the system call in the CGI is actually being served by the same process.  This does not work as the term signal likely is killing all process in the tree including the restarted boa process.

An alternative is to have a second instance of boa running that can restart the production instance.  While the production instance can restart the second instance used to restart the production instance.

Comment: Another option would be to use the batch processing facility. Something like `echo "/etc/init.d/boa.sh restart" | at now`. That would queue a job to run (approximately immediately) to restart the server, but it would be a child of the `atd` daemon, instead of being a child of `boa` that gets killed during the `stop` phase.

Comment: During the discussion we discovered that the distro of linux(an embedded type) does not support at or cron as that was another option I presented during chat.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, all very good information.  I'm going to try and come up with a solution this week, not sure if I want to go the twin Boa route.